# iOS Parse Facebook Login error 308 FBSDKLoginBadChallengeString

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement Facebook login in my iOS app, using Parse.

```
let permissionsArray = ["public_profile", "email"]

PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissionsArray)
    { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) in

    if let user = user {
        //we logged in!
    }
    else {
        //login error!
    }
}
```

This works well in the Simulator, but not on the device. On the device, I get this error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 308.)

Error code 308 is for [`FBSDKLoginBadChallengeString`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginConstants.h#L74), "The login response was missing a valid challenge string."

After I authorise my app on Facebook, this gets called:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

The url is:

`fb1640722449492705://authorize/#state=%7B%22challenge%22%3A%225OKWv3wN%2BEH%2BeQu48Xv6ty%2BRuek%3D%22%2C%22com.facebook.sdk_client_state%22%3Atrue%2C%223_method%22%3A1%2C%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%22564CD915-2CFC-4989-9AF6-CEA389908D51%22%7D&granted_scopes=user_birthday%2Cpublic_profile&denied_scopes=&signed_request=c8SBBDeaNpF-R_XTYx4LRA0BWm5p9IwXDr8M4nL3YXI.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&access_token=CAAXUOnbG6uEBANtAd9DzWBSu4LLOEcPsu86Ny0Ir`

Yes, I followed everything in [Parse's Facebook login guide](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook) (made sure that all bundle IDs match, implemented all required AppDelegate methods, etc).

What exactly does this error mean and how do you solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed it. This issue was caused by logging in with Parse **and** with `FBSDKLoginButton`.

Here's what I was doing:

```
//in my UI setup code:
let fbLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
fbLoginButton.addTarget(self, action: "fbButtonTouched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

....

func fbButtonTouched() {
    let permissionsArray = ["public_profile", "email"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissionsArray)
        { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) in

            if let user = user {
                //we logged in!
            }
            else {
                //login error!
            }
    }
}
```

I found out (the hard way) that *tapping* a `FBSDKLoginButton` attempts to log the user in! There was no need to also log the user in using `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`. So I just got rid of `fbButtonTouched()` and I could happily log in.

So what happened was that I was attempting two logins at the same time, which the simulator was happy with, but not the device.

If you want to know why, it's because the login authentication challenge it received [did not correspond to the one it was expecting](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.m#L142) because it received the one from the first log in attempt after it had sent the one from the second log in attempt and was therefore waiting for the second log in attempts' authentication challenge.

[The documentation for `FBSDKLoginButton`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginButton/) doesn't currently mention *anything* about the fact that tapping it initiates the log in flow, and because it's a subclass of `UIButton`, you'd think that you ought to `addTarget` to it and implement the login flow yourself. And having two logins at the same time leads to a misleading `FBSDKLoginBadChallengeString`. Recipe for disaster...

**EDIT:** The documentation has been updated correspondingly:

> `FBSDKLoginButton` works with `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` to determine what to display, **and automatically starts authentication when tapped (i.e., you do not need to manually subscribe action targets)**.

(my emphasis)

Comment: Eric - thanks for posting this answer. Saved me time. I had encountered something similar. My issue was trying to make the API call in a class level method. Seems like things fell out of scope, and the challenge was failing because the expected challenge was nil.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for the last couple of days and your answer is a timesaver. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks for the simple fix.  Hopefully this will be documented properly in the future in the SDK.

Comment: Same error for me, method called twice because I was adding FBLoginButton class to my custom button and also an IBAction to handle it.

Answer (score 49):

A simple solution work for me. Just enable Keychain Sharing in Capabilities

[image: Enable Keychain Sharing]

Comment: Worked for me, perfect!

Comment: You saved my life ! Thanks mate !

Comment: It worked. added a Keychain Group: com.facebook.sdk.login

Answer (score 15):

I only saw this error when I logged out, then logged back in.

My login and logout code were located in different files, as the relevant UI for login and logout are entirely different, and I had instantiated two separate FBSDKLoginManager instances. Consolidating to only one instance solved the problem for me.

Comment: This was my issue as well. I was creating a new FBSDKLoginManager() every time i logged in and out. This worked for me until 4.6.0, then it broke. Creating a shared FBSDKLoginManager instance fixed it.

Comment: Even I created singleton. Sometimes this error occur.

Comment: Solved with this guys! v4.7 Make a singleton! Thank you

Comment: This was my issue as well, after trying many other things I found this answer - thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I've followed the workaround from totvos and its working for me as well when using FBSDKLoginKit 4.7.1 & FBSDKCoreKit 4.8:

> Workaround...get the app built and copied to the phone, and then start
>   the app from the device (not the debugger). Then, attach the debugger
>   to the running process. This seems to get around whatever timing issue
>   is breaking this, and the various keychain operations appear to work
>   correctly while debugging.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4743#85335

---

Update:

This workaround didn't work all the time, so I ended up using @coco's answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31480026/877225

Comment: Running not from the debugger worked for me. Using SDK 4.8

Comment: Exactly, as noted in my update, it didn't work all the time, I rather have something that works all the time so I can debug and see exactly what users are going to see, instead of just wondering and hoping that it will just work for users.

Answer (score 15):

Apparently the only solution that worked for me is to add the Keychain Sharing Entitlement for the target.

You can find it in Project_name->target_name->Capabilities->Keychain Sharing

Comment: Similar fix to what Firebase is telling us to do.

Answer (score 14):

I found this problem when I upgraded to:

```
FBSDKCoreKit 4.4.0
FBSDKLoginKit 4.4.0
FBSDKShareKit 4.4.0.
```

It went away when I downgraded to:

```
FBSDKCoreKit 4.2.0
FBSDKLoginKit 4.1.0
FBSDKShareKit 4.1.0
```

I haven't had a chance to discover at what point the upgrades cause this - for example, could I have stuck with 4.3.0 for all three?

Comment: Same problem, resolution here, too. The error is reproducible on a clean app install when connecting to a user who has no previous FB connection, and the user unchecks one of the requested permissions (e.g. user_friends) during the dance in Facebook.app. Problem affects at least 4.4 and 4.3. Went away when I downgraded to 4.1. (We're using the login manager directly, not the button).

Comment: Downgrading from 4.5.0 to FBSDKCoreKit 4.2.0 FBSDKLoginKit 4.1.0 FBSDKShareKit 4.1.0 worked for me.

Comment: Hi are you all using pods please? Versions lower than 4.6 will have "does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled" link error for IOS 9. Do you have a workaround please?

Comment: This FB official doc "In order to support iOS 9, you should upgrade your Facebook iOS SDK 4.x to 4.6.0. If you are on 3.x of the SDK, you should move to v3.24. There are two key steps you follow after you upgrade to the SDK"

Comment: Does anyone know if this was fixed in 4.8.0?

Comment: *Does anyone know if this was fixed in 4.8.0?* - 
No it's not.

Comment: Still experiencing the issue on 4.8.0

Comment: Experiencing on 4.10.0.

Comment: as viggio24's comment, we don't need to downgrade. Just compile in release mode

Comment: This isn't working for me right now @WhiteMoney. When you say compile in release mode, do you mean go to `Product` -> `Scheme` -> `Edit Scheme` -> `Run` -> change `Build Configuration` to `Release` and uncheck `Debug Executable`?

Answer (score 8):

Try running your app straight from your device without having to launch it from your Xcode. Then login to Facebook w/o being bothered by 308. After that, you can resume launching from the Xcode to your device w/o the same issue.

This seems an issue between the FB SDK and iOS and not related to Parse. I'd appreciate it if someone could enlighten us on this subject.

My Xcode's version is 7.1, FB SDK is 4.8.x.

Comment: Logging in worked fine not launching it from Xcode for me.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I lost so much time on this one. fixed my problem on xcode 7.3.1 with FB 4.14.

Comment: cheers! thats tricky, what is the reason?, for other FB calls it works with xcode :/

Answer (score 7):

I'm using

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.8.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.8.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.8.0'
```

... and had the `code 308` problem when I logged out and logged in during the same session. Using `[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] logOut]` or `[facebookLoginManager logOut]` (with a persisted manager) just before calling `logInWithReadPermissions:` didn't work, but adding

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
```

before the `logInWithReadPermissions:` call works ok. (Tested in iOS 9.2.)

Comment: This works, and it's worth noting that it directly contradicts Facebook's documentation. The docs for "FKSDKManager.logOut()" say `This calls [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil] and [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil].`, which should be interoperable with the above.

Answer (score 4):

I also had error 308, however I was not using the Parse SDK.

These errors started appearing when I upgraded the Facebook iOS SDK from version `4.0.1` (`FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150402`) to one of the newer versions (`4.2.0` - `FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150528` or `4.3.0` - `FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150625`).

**Downgrading the [Facebook iOS SDK to version `4.0.1`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads) solved this problem for me.**

As a side note: the new versions of the SDK seem to correlate well with the appearance of 308 error posts on SO at the beginning of June.

Answer (score 4):

Before downgrading, I would try to clear out the local cache. I've had this problem when switching between Facebook accounts. Delete your app, force the Facebook to quit and then re-run everything and see if it persists. There may be a bug where Facebook is passing an old cached key that is no longer valid. Downgrading could be clearing the cache or the older version doesn't have the bug.

Comment: I forcefully quit the facebook app, removed my app and installed it again and got rid of the 308 error.  I previously only removed my app and reinstalled it, but that wasn't enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. So far just restarting my app worked. But I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

> if log out and login again without leaving this app,this error also
>   come,

```
let deletepermission = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/permissions/", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "DELETE")
            deletepermission.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection,result,error)-> Void in
                println("the delete permission is \(result)")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
                    FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                    AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegte().logout()
                })
            })
```

Answer (score 3):

Im using PFFacebookUtils 1.9.0 and FBSDKLoginKit 4.7.0
happend to me after logout and login(without restarting app)
solution - objective c:
just add     `[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] logOut];`
before      `[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`

Comment: I added `[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] logOut];` before login again solves my problems.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to resolve that kind of error :

1. Go to your project
2. Click Capabilities
3. Enable Keychain Access

Answer (score 2):

Official response from Facebook:

> We are already tracking this issue in another bug report, and it seems
>   to be an error on Apple's side.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/919990934704584/

Answer (score 2):

Use the same FBSDKLoginManager instance until logout, THEN create a new instance.

```
[fbLoginManager logOut];
fbLoginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to downgrade for this.

Perform the following things and it should work:
- Clean your derived data (Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Click on the small arrow next to Derived data). Make sure you read about derived data before performing this. If you have a complicated project and have made some silly mistakes (ex: deleted some file) you may have to figure out the issue before re running your app. But it won't be that difficult.
- Delete your app form your device/simulator
- Remove your Facebook app approval from Facebook (Setting -> App - > Click on the "x" to delete your app)

Rerun the app and everything should work.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Error code 308 is FBSDKLoginBadChallengeString

Using a shared instance for the FBSDKLoginManager solves the problem. I created a singleton that makes sure, only one FBSDKLoginManager gets instantiated.

I assume it has to do with the iOS9 Safari login, not 100% sure though

Comment: As @Kong Hantrakool mentioned, this issue still occurs with a singleton

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with: 
1.Add Bolts.framework 
2.in AppDelegate:  #import

Answer (score 0):

Update Facebook SDK to latest version solved this.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the authenticationChallenge issue when you mistakenly try to login twice simultaneously and then further logins will give you some keychain warning on console while debugging, this error will be noticeable when you will be debugging on device. Without debugging mode you'll not get this error, the reason is keychain will work fine when you are not debugging.

There are few workarounds for this:
1. Try logging in without debugging mode and once it succeeded you can further login successfully with debugging mode too.
2. Check for error code **FBSDKLoginBadChallengeString** and call `[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]` to clear token and perform login again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I was trying to catch login and logout event as below

```
loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
// Handle clicks on the button
[loginButton
 addTarget:self
 action:@selector(loginButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Once the button is clicked, show the login dialog
-(void)loginButtonClicked
{
  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [login
    logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
          fromViewController:self
                     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
      NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Logged in");
    }
  }];
}
```

But this is only good for a custom login button, if you are using default fb login button, the FBSDKLoginManager has been initialized already, you will get the error when trying to create another one.

So, in order to catch login and logout event, just set the delegate for login button and then handle it like the following:

```
    loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.delegate = self;


- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {
        [self getFBProfile];
    }
}

- (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton {
    [self logout];
}
```