# FBSDKLoginManager fails with error code - 308

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

We are using **FBSDKLoginManager** with our own UI for login to facebook. However sometimes the login fails with the error code `308`.

As per docs the reason is - `FBSDKLoginBadChallengeString`, I have searched all over the internet to find out the reason for this but have had no luck.

Any explanation as to why this error occurs and how to resolve it?

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643122/ios-parse-facebook-login-error-308-fbsdkloginbadchallengestring

Comment: .. and this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31480026/383919

Answer (score 3):

The reason I had this error was that my login and logout code used two different instances of the FBSDKLoginManager.

see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659830/4068264

(I do not have the reputation for comments so apologies to the community if this response does not fall in the category of "Answer")

Answer (score 1):

This is how I reproduced and solved the com.facebook.sdk.login error 308.

User A logs to Facebook, then logs into my app, finally logs out of my app using the popular:

```
func logOutFromFacebook(){

   if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){

           let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
           loginManager.logOut()
    }
}
```

Now User B logs into Facebook, logs into my app and com.facebook.sdk.login error 308 shows up.

If I reinstall the app the new user can login without problems but certainly I don't want people reinstalling the app every time there is an account switch.

The solution that has solved this problem was to use  FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil) as below:

```
func logOutFromFacebook(){

   if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){

     FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)

        By itself I had no use for it, maybe you might want to uncomment.
        //   let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        //   loginManager.logOut()

    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

How to fix issue in **iOS10** for **Facebook Login**

```
Error OSStatus -10814 occures when canOpenURL: can't find any application, that can open this URL (actually, Facebook trying to find their application by calling canOpenURL: with argument "fbauth2:/"). Printing happens inside of function, so you can't do anything with that. But if you will run your application on device with installed Facebook app, you will not see this error.

Error 308 occures because of the situation, when value, stored in keychain is not equal to value, that is stored in facebook completion parameters (for more information you can check -[FBSDKLoginManager completeAuthentication:expectChallenge:]).

It happens because Apple changed the way of working with keychain in iOS 10. To fix this issue you simply should go to **Targets**->**Capabilities** and **enable keychain sharing** (it enables access to keychain for your app):
```

After that you can get the data for Facebook.

Hopefully, it will helps you.

Thanks Mandeep Singh

Comment: I have enabled keychain access in xcode but still getting 308 error. I have tried a lot. Please help.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya, yes mam how may I help you. Can you give me brief description about your issue

Comment: I am getting "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 308.)" when try to login with facebook.  
I am using SDK 4.22.1.

Comment: Can you share your project with me so that I can review it properly and will provide you update asap.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pods

```
  pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.5.0'
  pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.5.0'
  pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.5.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.37.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.37.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.37.0'
```

Also call logOut() on FBSDKLoginManager before login

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pods

```
 pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.5.0'
 pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.5.0'
 pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.5.0'
 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.37.0'
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.37.0'
 pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.37.0'
```

Also call logOut() on FBSDKLoginManager before login