# Why am I getting com.facebook.sdk.login error 308?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Xcode 7.0, testing on iOS 9.0.2 and using Facebook SDK 4.7.0.

When I am logging in a user, most of the time everything works as it should, however sometimes I keep getting this error and I have no idea why!

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 308.)

After researching I have seen that some people are getting the error when logging in with parse.com's `FBUtils` and the official `FBSDK` at the same time, however I am only using `FBSDK` in my project.

So my question is, why am I getting this error and how do I get rid of it?

**Edit - Adding Code**

Here is my login logic:

```
func loginWithFacebook(sender: UIViewController, completion: (profile: FBSDKProfile?, token: String?, cancelled: Bool, error: String?) -> Void ) {

    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver( sender , selector: "onProfileUpdated:", name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email", "public_profile"], fromViewController: sender) { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR")
            completion(profile: nil, token: nil, cancelled: false, error: error.localizedDescription)
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        } else if result.isCancelled {
            print("CANCELLED")
            completion(profile: nil, token: nil, cancelled: true, error: nil)

        } else {
            print("NO ERROR")
            if FBSDKProfile.currentProfile() == nil {
                print("PROFILE IS NIL")
                completion(profile: nil, token: result.token.tokenString, cancelled: false, error: nil)
            } else {
                print("PROFILE IS NOT NIL")
                completion(profile: FBSDKProfile.currentProfile(), token: result.token.tokenString, cancelled: false, error: nil)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: May be this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643122/ios-parse-facebook-login-error-308-fbsdkloginbadchallengestring

Comment: Try again without attaching the debugger, my facebook sdk gives me this error when connected to xcode but works when running without debugger.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

For **Xcode8 - iOS10**,

**Enable** Keychain Sharing within Capabilities tab of target fixed my issue.

[image]

More details can be found here : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/51

---

For **Xamarin Studio** (Suggested by @Kenneth),

Add the **Entitlements.plist** file to **Custom Entitlements** under the `iOS Bundle Signing` options in the iOS project.

Comment: It worked for me as well with Xamarin Studio.
I had to add the "Entitlements.plist" file to "Custom Entitlements" under the "iOS Bundle Signing" options in the iOS project.

Comment: I know saying thanks isn't great. But this does work. And you don't need to 'add the keychain sharing feature to your App ID' for it to work so don't freakout immediately. Thanks dewd.

Comment: Worked for me! But why this is a solution. Why I need to do this?

Comment: @Developer ,  iOS 10 having keychain turned on in the app capabilities (having an entry in entitlements file) is a requirement for using keychain.
More info : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/51

Comment: Its working for me as well. Thanks
Is Apple mentioned this settings officially?

Comment: @msmq It's good that worked for you,  I don't find any official docs for this but have a look my comment above given to `Developer`, that may help.

Comment: @ZaidPathan does it work on real device (not simulator) and do I need to add keychain capability for my appID on my apple developer account?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Yes It works on real device and you need to enable it on AppID as well.

Comment: @ZaidPathan thanks, but it seems there is no such option http://take.ms/Ze9wY for app ID, so I only need to turn keychain capability on in Xcode because I don't need to share keychain between applications.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Thanks for sharing this, I was using Xcode 8 so thought it was automatically enabled to my AppID, but didn't know this option isn't there.

Comment: Downgraded FACEBOOK SDK version from 4.3.8 to 1.37.0
Solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution to this problem. I was creating an instance of the login manager where i needed it:

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
```

Then i was using it to login and I was creating another instance in my logout method. I fixed the issue by creating a lazy variable to be used throughout the app:

```
lazy var fbLoginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = {
   return FBSDKLoginManager()
}()
```

**UPDATE**

Facebook are aware of the bug and are looking into it. I have found that my solution doesn't always work and have updated my code to the following and have not seen it since:

```
private var _fbLoginManager: FBSDKLoginManager?

var fbLoginManager: FBSDKLoginManager {
    get {
        if _fbLoginManager == nil {
            _fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        }
        return _fbLoginManager!
    }
}
```

When logging out of Facebook, you need to call `_fbLoginManager = nil` and the instance will be recreated when it is used to log in the next time. The issue seems to happen more often when using the same instance to log back in after logging out yet the issue happens even more when there are multiple instances of `FBSDKLoginManager` so declaring it as stated above seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: This one works for me, I think the best way is to put the FBSDKLoginManager as a single instance into your AppDelegate. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, i should add that this code is in my UserManager.swift class which is a singleton

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these solutions work for FBSDK 4.8.0 - a single persistent instance does not, nor does clearing that single instance on logout, and then re-instantiating on login

Comment: Could you elaborate on where to place these?

Comment: You put these into the class that you need to use the FBLoginManager in, so instead of having a var or a let, you do it this way

Answer (score 5):

October 2018.

Reason: "+" sign is replaced by " " in challengeReceived string. Issue in FBSDK.

Quick and dirty fix: 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/pull/922

Specifically, replace line 233 in FBSDKLoginManager:

```
NSString *challengeExpected = [self loadExpectedChallenge];
```

with

```
NSString *challengeExpected = [[self loadExpectedChallenge] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: Oh wow, I have the same problem on their latest SDKs. This is major. Does Facebook know about this? If so, what do they say about it? Is it not better to adjust the challengeReceived? If Facebook rolls it back and challengeReceived comes back again with "+" the software will then again not work.

Comment: OK, I think the issue is known by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/954033164793390/?disable_redirect=0

In the bug it says that version 4.37.0 is working fine.
I think the best fix is to roll back FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit to 4.37.0 and then wait with updating until Facebook released a fix.

Comment: v4.38.1 (and above) has this fix. Check https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/pull/922

Comment: v4.38.1 did not updated in Cocopods, 4.38.0 only available. So i roll back to 4.37.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem is solved with 4.9.0. I had the same problem and it's fixed with new SDK version.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x

Comment: still it is not fixed .

Answer (score 1):

Fix available in `facebook-objc-sdk` https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/releases/tag/sdk-version-4.38.1 and above.

Comment: But please don't forget that you still need to enable Keychain sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error the reason was in my case:
AuthentificationController on which was Facebook login button was presented without navigation controller.
To resolve this error i just added navigation controller and sat my AuthentificationController as root.